# OpenDistro Kibana Monitor shows no data

Tags: logstash, kibana, elk, metricbeat, elasticsearch-opendistro

So i got the new version of Opendistro ELK stack, including Kibana 1.3. and i got metricbeat and logstash as well but now im trying to create a monitor for alerting purposes, but when i select an index from the list it shows no data what so ever, i tried both the graph visualization and query but no luck.

here is my kibana setup:

```
server.host: "172.31.2.197"
elasticsearch.hosts: http://172.31.2.197:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
#elasticsearch.username: admin
#elasticsearch.password: admin
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]
opendistro_security.enabled: false
opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
#opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
#opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"
```

Is there anyway i can fix this, im really desperate right now please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to request directly the elasticsearch cluster with the "Dev Tools" panel (left menu), the request looks like :

```
GET myindex/_search 
{
"query":{
"match_all": {}
}
}
```

With this on, you just validate that Kibana access correctly to your data index.